# Fire events on overlapping layers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

I need to fire event on two overlapping layers, like in this example:
[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4B6p/5/).

As you saw in example I managed to get click event working, but I also need the other events like hover, as if the overlay would have the css property:

```
pointer-events:none;
```

But still launch events on the overlay.

Comment: _I need to fire event on two overlapping layers, like in example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4B6p/_......didnot find it.

Comment: What do you mean by first layer? You mean you want your `button` `div` to be clickable and hover to change color?

Comment: yes, I whant it to act as if an overlay would have the pointer-events:none; property, but still lounch the events on the overlay

Comment: Why would you have an element on top of these buttons anyway? This goes against the accessibility guidelines and would probably just confuse users.

Comment: Its a strange thing to ask why I ask just because you cant provide the answer. I really need that feature for dialog boxes, it's working, just looks weird when the rest of the site shuts down the hovering.

Comment: The problem you have with `hover` is that the events are generated on a positional basis. Turning off and on the overlay will not send a hover-in event as the cursor *is already in the button element*. You would need to catch each event type in the larger overlay element and send explicit hover-in and hover-out events based on tracking the cursor position. While this is all doable, you are basically creating a completely custom windowing system. re "just because you cant provide the answer", please remember *you are asking everyone else for free help* so be nice :)

Comment: Yes, thats exactly why I ask, to see if there's a workaround. And about being nice- I myself was answering questions consistently on my other account and expect my answer to be answered the same way.